# How to Delete node_modules - Deep Nested Folder in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm

Upon trying to remove the **node_modules** directory created by `npm install`:

> The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file
>   system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try
>   renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation

I also tried <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> and still having the same issue.

Comment: `try renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,@SLaks! I should have mentioned that I tried that too, but the files and dirs are many and deep, it has things like **C:\Users\my_user_name\projs\backend\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\camelcase-keys\node_modules\...** and it goes on. It's impractical to rename files manually and I hope there will be easier ways without writing a program

Comment: Webstorm can delete all.

Comment: I used the Long Path Fixer tool and successfully removed this ".meteor" folder. (https://long-path-fixer.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: RUN INSTALL, npm install rimraf -g, RUN DELETE, rimraf node_modules

Comment: Npkill is the best option as of 3/2020.  npm i -g npkill , then run via: npkill

Comment: Use `npx npkill` to delete all node_modules in a folder. It will list all of the subfolders containing node_modules. You can select using cursor and space to delete for a particular folder

Answer (score 692, accepted):

Since this the top google result, this is what worked for me:

Update, if you have npm v5, use [npx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62917293/1822977):

`npx rimraf --glob **/node_modules`

Otherwise install RimRaf:

`npm install rimraf -g`

And in the project folder delete the node_modules folder with:

`rimraf --glob node_modules`

If you want to recursively delete:

`rimraf --glob .\**\node_modules`

[ http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/nodejs/how-to-delete-node_modules-folder-on-windows-machine/ ]

Comment: not working here: "Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty". and supplied link not working!

Comment: I'm the author of the blog post. @olefrank: this tends to happen when you try to delete the whole folder (not just node_modules), and also if you happen to have the folder opened in an Explorer window. usagidon, thanks for linking the original source.

Comment: That won't be useful if you don't have NodeJS, or you're trying to delete the global modules of NodeJS after uninstalling it (that is why I had to use robocopy)

Comment: You can delete anz other folder with rimraf, not only node_modules

Comment: This only works if rimraf is not a (transient) dependency of your project. Otherwise there will be an error: The system cannot find the path specified. Any solution for that?

Comment: I'll add my 2 cents here to be a bit more specific to the question. You can delete all the node_modules folders recursively (using globbing pattern) like this:
`rimraf .\**\node_modules`

Comment: Just a note: on Windows 10 I got an error, then ran rimraf in an admin powershell and every worked! Great answer!

Comment: One-liner: `npx rimraf node_modules`. Npx is included with NPM 5.2+ and is a eXecutor for npm packages, which automatically downloads missing npm packages.

Comment: @Artif3x 's commnent should be marked as the best answer loll! thanks for the tip for deleting recursively :-)

Comment: `rimraf ./**/node_modules` when running on linux or macs

Comment: `rimraf` didn't work for me, even as Administrator. Same goes for many of the answers (`robocopy`, `rmdir`, Winrar, Visual Studio Code, etc.) below. What did work was renaming folders along the problem path to much shorter names. `node_modules` became `n`, `my-long-project-name` became `m', and so on. I then deleted the `n` folder with no problems. Finally, I chose a Linux distribution to develop under forever more.

Comment: This post is old, but still helpful. Maybe somebody knows for certain, but it seems like the glob pattern results in a recursive search for "node_modules" within node_modules which can take quite some time. Is this the case? If so, is there a way to skip searching in node_modules?

Comment: Updates: I am getting an "Error: Illegal characters in path" via `rimraf .\**\node_modules` with the latest version. It confused me and I've just got an answer to resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281066/error-illegal-characters-in-path-in-npm-rimraf/75309179#75309179

Answer (score 136):

I've simply done that by using Winrar, this may seem a strange solution but working very well.

- right click on `node_modules` folder
- select `Add to archive ...` from the menu.
- Winrar dialog opens
- just check the option `delete files after archiving`
- Don't forget to delete the node_modules.rar after finished.

---

[UPDATE]
This also works with 7Zip

---

[image]

Comment: wow this is sneaky! +1 Been using robocopy tho apparently this has been fixed with new npm or something.

Comment: @ChrisS How does it workt with 7Zip? Especially when using the GUI!

Comment: In 2016 (and especially 2018) you shouldn't have to be this clever to delete a bunch of files.

Comment: yeah, you'd think if winrar can figure it out they could get the window shell to do it.....

Comment: @bennos, it works similarly with 7-Zip. Choose `Add to Archive` to open the GUI. There is an option `Delete files after compression`.

Comment: Adding files to the archive is taking way too much time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 93):

DELETE only by using DOS command without any installation:

Create an empty folder "test" on C or D drive and use following DOS command

```
robocopy /MIR c:\test D:\UserData\FolderToDelete > NUL
```

After completing above command, your folder will be empty, now you can delete the folder.

Don't worry your test folder will always be empty, so you can delete it at any time.

Comment: best answer, because you don´t need to install anything

Comment: After trying rimraf and adding a network folder, this is the cleanest solution I've found. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: great solution; easy.

Comment: I just made a minor addion: `> NUL`. When I just tried this, it was being throttle by the console, and was going to take 15 minutes or more. With the redirection in place, it finished in about 2

Comment: It's funny that in order to delete some JS files, you need yet another JS library.

Comment: +1 for this (also I upvoted).

I had issues with the rimraf approach due to getting permission denied on a few files under `node_modules/.bin`. The robocopy approach worked, when nothing else would.

Answer (score 80):

I used GitBash to remove de folder!

```
rm -r node_modules
```

It took a while to delete everything, but worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me. I was using rimraf earlier. rimraf didn't work and i tried this.

Comment: This should be top comment. Not, installing something just to remove something.. Alternatively just type ```RD node_modules```

Comment: For deleting all *node_modules* folders in a folder with multiple projects use : `rm -r ./**/node_modules`.

Comment: It takes for a while(one hour and more...). But it works

Answer (score 43):

You can use Git Bash to remove the folder:

example:
*c:\users\olefrank\projects\mynodeproject*

> rm -rf /c/users/olefrank/projects/mynodeproject

Comment: This did not work on Windows 7. Directory not empty error

Comment: You need to specify the -d flag also, that will also delete directories.

Comment: or -fR to recursively climb to the top and delete the folder as well

Comment: @Karthiga -rf are flags/options/parameters that tell the RM how to perform the delete operation.  `r` says to recurse into any subdirectories and `f` says to force deletion (don't prompt).  `-rf` is a unix convention to specify multiple flags/options at once.

Comment: For PowerShell, `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path node_modules` or batch, `rmdir /s node_modules`. PS can use shortcuts which bring the first command to `rm -fo -r node_modules`.

Answer (score 29):

I think this was not mentioned before. but the best way to delete unwanted `node_modules` is to install an utility called `npmkill`.

#### Installation:

From your terminal:

```
npm i -g npkill
```

#### And to use it:

From your terminal:

```
npkill
```

or alternatively, you can directly use it without installation by writing:

```
npx npkill
```

You will then be presented with a list of projects, and by hitting space bar you can delete their `node_modules`.

Answer (score 24):

**Try Visual Studio Code**

After trying many solution i find this one is pretty simple.
just open the project in Visual code and delete it. the UI may freeze for some seconds but it will definitely works.I test using many large size node_modules folder with it

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Strangely works!! :) I've been trying to delete it even in Safe mode, even used `sudo su` but nothing helps. BTW, I'm running on OSX which never happened to me until I upgraded to Mojave.

Comment: Works with Windows 10, too, though I had to use the command multiple times.

Comment: Smart idea, but sadly did not go any faster for me in my angular project

Comment: Many thanks, worked like champ. Other solutions did not work for me.

Comment: slow. down vote

Answer (score 24):

Please save yourself the need to read most of these answers and just use npx rather than trying to install rimraf globally. You can run a single command and always have the most recent version with none of the issues seen here.

```sh
npx rimraf ./**/node_modules
```

Comment: Best answer around. It's fast, it works, and it's smarter than throwing "-g"s around.

Answer (score 22):

## Delete Deep Netsted Folder like node_modules in Windows

1. **Option 1**

   Delete using `rimraf` NPM package

   - Open command prompt and change your directory to the folder where 
     `node_modules` folder exists.
   - Run

     `rimraf node_modules`
   - Missing rimraf ERROR then Install

     `npm install rimraf -g`
   - When the installation completes, run

     `rimraf node_modules`
2. **Option 2**:

   Detele without installing anything

   - Create a folder with name `test` in any Drive

     `robocopy /MIR c:\test D:\UserData\FolderToDelete > NUL`
   - delete the folder `test` and `FolderToDelete` as both are empty

Why this is an issue in windows?

One of the deep nested folder structure is node_modules, **Windows can’t delete the folder as its name is too long**. To solve this, Easy solution, install a node module ***RimRaf***

Comment: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted`

Comment: **Fixed:** I had to restart my computer. Something was using `node_modules`, but it was giving me a permission error.

Answer (score 13):

simple just run for **windows I haven't tested it for other operating systems**

```
rm -r node_modules
```

in fact, you can delete any folder with this.

like ***rm -r AnyFolderWhichIsNotDeletableFromShiftDeleteOrDelete.***

just open the **gitbash** move to root of the folder and run this command

Hope this will help.

Thanks,
Ajay Kotnala

Comment: It doesn't work for node_modules for me. I still get errors about the folders not being empty.

Comment: For PowerShell, `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path node_modules` or batch, `rmdir /s node_modules`. PS can use shortcuts which bring the first command to `rm -fo -r node_modules`.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows Platform the simplest way is to use the terminal.
Please Run the command RMDIR /Q/S **foldername** to delete the folder and all of its subfolders.

Example: RMDIR /Q/S node_modules

The Above Command deletes **node_modules** folder and its subfolders.
For information please visit this https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/18/how-to-delete-large-folders-in-windows-super-fast/

Answer (score 6):

You can use Git Bash to remove the folder:

example:
*c:\users\stu\projects\mynodeproject*

> rm /c/users/stu/projects/mynodeproject -rfd

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and RD didn't work, for some unknown reason.

NPM can get rid of its own mess though, so if you do `npm uninstall [module-name]` for each directory in node_modules, you'll get rid of them.

(I'll look up how to batch loop this later, for those who have lots of dependencies.)

Answer (score 5):

1. `npm install -g remove-node-modules`
2. cd to root and `remove-node-modules`
3. or `remove-node-modules path/to/folder`

Source:

https://github.com/j-quelly/node-cleanup

Answer (score 5):

I just do **del node_modules** inside my project folder on PowerShell, it will ask you if you want to remove it and its children folder, just hit 'Y' and that's it

Comment: Simple one. Thank you

Comment: ...\node_modules has children and the Recurse parameter was
not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
rd : Directory C:\...\node_modules\ngx-color-picker\dist cannot be removed
because it is not empty.  
rd node_modules -recurse

Comment: rd node_modules -recurse

Comment: @AUSTX_RJL rd also works, but I never had a problem with del node_modules.. wired, but tnx any way for another way of deleting in PS

Answer (score 5):

I always use the GitBash for this purpose.

Run the below command in GitBash and it will delete `node_modules` folder very **faster**.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Comment: For PowerShell, `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path node_modules` or batch, `rmdir /s node_modules`. PS can use shortcuts which bring the first command to `rm -fo -r node_modules`.

Answer (score 4):

The PowerShell way:

```bsh
PS > rm -r -force node_modules

# The same, but without using aliases
PS > Remove-Item -Recurse -Force node_modules
```

And if you want to delete every `node_modules` in sub directories:

**Note Potentially dangerous as it deletes recursively, be sure of what you're doing here**

```bsh
PS > dir -Path . -Filter node_modules -recurse | foreach {echo $_.fullname; rm -r -Force $_.fullname}
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to clean up an entire Projects directory for backup purposes, so I installed rimraf and ran this at the root dir (inside a git bash prompt):

```
find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -exec rimraf '{}' +
```

Very effective, truly recursive (avoids children node_modules) and fast on windows (thanks to rimraf).

Sources:

1. https://rtmccormick.com/2018/01/10/clear-node-modules-folders-recursively-mac-linux/
2. The accepted answer in this question that suggests rimraf but lacks in the recursive aspect

Answer (score 3):

Just use powershell..

Run powershell and cd to the parent folder and then:

```
rm [yourfolder]
```

as in:

```
rm node_modules
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried everything but didn't work. All the above methods did nothing. At last I was able to delete via VSCode.

1. Just Open your root folder with VSCode.
2. Select `node_modules` folder and delete.
3. Profit. (It will take `few milliseconds` to delete.)

[image: VSCode-delete.png]

Answer (score 3):

I made a Windows context item to fast delete node_modules or other folders.
I use it when Windows doesn't delete a folder because of some invalid chars in the directory path.

### HOW TO INSTALL?

1. **Install rimraf**  => `npm install rimraf -g`
2. Create a new file named `delete.bat`, set the content as below and copy it into `c:\windows\system32\`

   **delete.bat:**

```sh
 @ECHO OFF
 ECHO.
 ECHO %CD% 
 ECHO.
 ECHO Are you sure to delete the folder with Rimraf?
 PAUSE
 SET FOLDER=%CD%
 CD /

 rimraf "%FOLDER%"

 rem DEL /F/Q/S "%FOLDER%" > NUL
 rem RMDIR /Q/S "%FOLDER%"

 EXIT
```

3. Run **fast-delete.reg** file to import into registry.

   **Done!**

[image: final result]

Comment: Complete article in https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/18/how-to-delete-large-folders-in-windows-super-fast/

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, using [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) all you have to do is select the folder click <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> . Don't forget about the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

Comment: This is the best solution! TC deletes the folder with no hiccups and it's really fast

Answer (score 2):

Any file manager allow to avoid such issues, e.g [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=en)

[image]

Comment: I hadn't seen anyone using that kinda interface for 10+ years now.. J made my day.

Answer (score 1):

### One solution that I use:

*(I would prefer to avoid installing a new extension (rimraf) when working with CI environments.)*

1. **A)** Rename packages.json to something else. **B)** Specially on CI - after npm install, I usually remove the file instead of renaming it, but if you need it, you don't have to do this. That's your choice.
2. run `npm init` - this will create an empty `packages.json` file (no dependencies)
3. run `npm prune` - this will match *node_modules* with the dependencies section of `packages.json` - which is now empty as the result of step #2.
4. If you have chosen **#1.A.** step, delete the newly created `packages.json`, and rename original `packages.json` back to its original name.

Answer (score 1):

Its too easy.

**Just delete all folders inside node_modules and then delete actual node_module folder.**

This Works for me. Best luck....

Comment: Honestly, this is the faster way but a lot of patience is required. Even better if you delete a few folders at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, even if you install `rimraf` globally you can have a local `rimraf` dependency (SASS usually have it). In this case I would run following commands:

Follow first 2 steps as [usagidon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29685530/2869931) recommended, if you have issues or errors try

```
npm uninstall rimraf & rimraf node_modules
```

this will delete local `rimraf` and use the global one

Answer (score 1):

On Windows my go to solution is using the [`rmdir` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd):

`rd /S .\node_modules\`

If it fails the first time -- try one more time.
Also check if you have running scripts currently using the modules (`npm run serve` or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Use this with CMD

```
npx rimraf node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

From this looks of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#maxpath), it looks like you can now bypass the MAX_PATH restriction in Windows 10 v1607 (AKA 'anniversary update') by changing a value in the registry - or via Group Policy

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows 10 and I could'nt delete folders with message "directory not emtpy". Neither *rimraf* nor *rm -rf* worked.

Copying an empty text file to every single folder did the trick - I was able to delete the complete node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly related, but as this is the first post I found in my search for a similar solution I think it's worth posting here.

I was running into permission issues on Windows 10 trying to delete my node_modules folder after a failed attempt at installing electron-redux. It seems electron-redux added @types to my node_modules, which had incorrect permissions set up.

rimraf did not work as it still ran into permission issues.

I ended up renaming node_modules then a simple delete worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my problem was that i had .bin folder inside node_modules and i wasn't able to delete that, I tried all the above solutions for the same but nothing worked.

Error which was repeating was "u do not have permission to delete the folder or its been used by some other program".

Solution that i found  "I had Antivirus installed on my pc ,which was unknowingly using the files from node_modules folder".

I uninstalled the antivirus or u can change permission setting from antivirus setting option (depends on which antivirus u have).Now i am able to delete  node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows

Run below to remove files under `node_modules` and sub directories & also remove folders in it:

```
DEL /F/S/Q node_modules > NUL 2>&1  &  RMDIR /S/Q node_modules > NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of rimraf doesn't work with double asterisk (i.e. **rimraf .**\node_modules**). Solution is to use older version:

```
npm i rimraf@3.0.2 -g
```

and then run

```
rimraf .\**\node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

**For windows users**

```
> cd work_directory 
> FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

**For linux users**

```
$ cd work_directory 
$ find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune | xargs du -chs
```

this will help to delete all deep nested node_modules in your directory

Answer (score -1):

**Advance a little beat** for multiple folders...

If you have a project folder with multiple 'builds' that contains 'node_module'. Like:

```
C:/Project/build-1/node_modules
C:/Project/build-2/node_modules
C:/Project/build-3/node_modules
C:/Project/build-4/node_modules
```

You want to delete all folders starts with "build"

! First install **nodejs** and **rimraf** as suggested above !

Then go to path with project and run PowerShell command

```
cd  C:/Project/
Get-ChildItem build* | foreach {rimraf -Path $_.FullName}
```

It will take a wile

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was:

1. closed the node manager console
2. closed the Atom (visual studio code ) dev environment you are in.
3. then delete the node_modules

   ```
   npm install rimraf -g 
   rimraf node_modules
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You may use another npm package specifically for this purpose. 
By installing it locally in the folder using

`npm i rm-node-modules-recur`

If you wish you can also install it globally with -g switch.

If installed locally you can invoke the binary from current directory node_modules.bin\ using

```
 .\node_modules\.bin\rmnodes "<top level directory within quotes>"
```

If you chose global installation simply use

```
rmnodes "<top level directory within quotes>"
```

and thats it .. this package will end up deleting node_modules from all sub directories recursively (in my case some 60 odd folders) with ease. refer attached snapshot. 
[using rm-node-modules-recur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxQKL.png)

Answer (score -2):

You can make simple batch based on **@mike-caron** answer so you don't need to type every time whole `robocopy` command instead just input path to selected folder:

```
@echo off
ECHO What Directory would you like to empty?
ECHO Current path: %cd%
SET /p UserInputPath=Input relative path to directory:
ROBOCOPY /MIR empty_dir %cd%\%UserInputPath% > NUL
PAUSE
```

Here you are using empty directory named *empty_dir* in `robocopy` command that needs to be in same directory with batch file for this to work. After batch file finishes its job both selected directory and *empty_dir* directory will be empty so that you can remove them.

I made a simple batch file that creates empty folder and after `robocopy` command is executed removes both empty folder and selected folder so that only thing you need to do is enter path to selected folder that you want to delete. 
It is fast and practical if you don't want to install stuff like **rimraf**.
You can download it here https://github.com/5imun/WinCleaner