# Windows 10 completely unable to open js file, access denied

Tags: node.js, windows, permissions, gulp, uac

I'm trying to run a gulp script. But I'm getting this permission related error.

```
fs.js:584
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'd:\CODE\project\node_modules\ttf2woff2\jssrc\ttf2woff2.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:421:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\CODE\project\node_modules\ttf2woff2\jssrc\index.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

My OS: Windows 10

Node version: v5.9.1

I've set the permissions of `project` folder to read/write for all users recursively via folder security in windows and i've tried running the gulp task as admin.

More info

When I try to open `ttf2woff2\jssrc\ttf2woff2.js` in notepad **as administrator** I get: `You don't have permission to open this file, contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission`.

- I have taken full ownership of the file
- I have created a permission rule for `Everyone` with full access
- I've tried copying the file via `cmd` as administrator to another directory but get access denied.
- I've tried downloading the [file direct from github](https://github.com/nfroidure/ttf2woff2/blob/master/jssrc/ttf2woff2.js) via chrome instead of via npm and still cannot open it.
- I've disabled UAC
- I've tried viewing the raw code on git and copying it into a file I've created. This just gives me a javascript error when running the gulp task, I suspect that it's how displaying all the code due to its side, the indentation leaves me thinking it's cutting off at 44k lines.

Still cannot get into it.

[image]

Comment: Have exactly the same problem now. Did you ever found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Kiee, I had exactly the same problem. We could troubleshoot this in more ways that you want to try. However, I like the clean slate approach when all else fails. Get yourself the node tool **["rimraf"](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf)**.

```
npm install rimraf
```

run rimraf on the node_modules folder

```
rimraf "C:\...\node_modules"
```

Reboot your system if possible.

install all your node packages

```
npm install
```

**What could be happening?**

Any number of things up to and including the folder/file not existing and Windows explorer not recognizing that fact. Yes, that happened.

Comment: This is absolutely not an answer to the question : OC question regards windows permission loosing, while this answer only provides a remove tool for npm.

Comment: @Riduidel, I beg to differ. Please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175200/unable-to-delete-node-modules-folder-windows-7). This is the very reason why I came across **rimraf** in the first place. It's not  a matter of opinion. It's a matter of fact. You can do the exercise in Windows 7.