# RangeError: Invalid array buffer length - Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, npm

I was just coding (Meteor JS) when this error started to crop up, and I'm not even sure what caused it:

```
buffer.js:25                                                                      
const ui8 = new Uint8Array(size);                                             
            ^
RangeError: Invalid array buffer length                                           
at new ArrayBuffer (native)                                                   
at new Uint8Array (native)                                                    
at createBuffer (buffer.js:25:17)                                             
at allocate (buffer.js:96:12)                                                 
at new Buffer (buffer.js:56:12)                                               
at increaseBufferIfNecessary (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mtos.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\stream-buffers\lib\writable_streambuffer.js:58:23)                                               
at [object Object]._write (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mtos.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\streambuffers\lib\writable_streambuffer.js:65:5)                                                   
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:300:12)                                       
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:286:5)                                  
at [object Object].Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:214:11)                
at Request.ondata (stream.js:31:26)                                           
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)                                                  
at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)                                             
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous
(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mtos.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\request\request.js:1255:12)                                                                    
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)                                                  
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)                                     
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)                              
at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)                 
at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:124:22)                           
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:320:20)                            
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)                                                  
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)                                           
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)                              
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)                       
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

I've tried to `npm cache clear` but it hasn't helped. What could be causing this error? Is it my code or is it something else?

Comment: One hint might be to understand what is the value of `size` on the line that throws the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I'm a bit of a n00b. How do I find the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in windows 10 and I also get this error after meteor started auto updating.

So here's what I did:

1) I remove dirs node_modules and .meteor/local:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf .meteor/local
```

2) `meteor npm install`

3) run meteor with: `meteor`

## UPDATE

After trying the above and running meteor it worked but then after some time it started thworing same error. So I read somewhere to uninstall and install meteor again in Windows and that solved the error. Maybe try unistalling and installing it again if facing this bug

Comment: take care when remove local because there are bd folder inside local folder

Answer (score 0):

Win 10.

I had to reinstall meteor to make it work again.

Right after uninstalling you need remove `x:/Users/${yourUser}/AppData/Local/.meteor` folder. That can require rimraf as described here: [Unable to delete node_modules folder (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175200/unable-to-delete-node-modules-folder)

`npm install rimraf -g`
`rimraf .meteor`