# RangeError: Invalid array buffer length Error - Reaction Commerce Installation

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to install reaction commerce (reactioncommerce.com) in Google Compute engine with f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory) server configuration. I am getting while starting the reaction commerce in gcloud shell.

Please guide me what i should do.

```
zenmonk@eshop::~/reaction reaction init shop 

    Cloning the master branch of Reaction from Github...
    Cloning into 'shop'...
    Installing NPM packages...
    npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
    dtrace-provider@0.6.0 install /home/zenmonk/reaction/shop/node_modules/dtrace-provider
    node scripts/install.js
    fibers@1.0.13 install /home/zenmonk/reaction/shop/node_modules/fibers
    node build.js || nodejs build.js
    linux-x64-v8-4.5 exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    reaction@0.14.2 postinstall /home/zenmonk/reaction/shop
    .reaction/scripts/postinstall.sh
    reaction@0.14.2 /home/zenmonk/reaction/shop

Reaction successfully installed!
To start your Reaction instance, just run:
cd shop
reaction

zenmonk@eshop@:~/reaction/shop$ reaction

Using settings file at settings/dev.settings.json

Setting up plugin imports...

[[[[[ ~/reaction/shop ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
buffer.js:25
const ui8 = new Uint8Array(size);
^

RangeError: Invalid array buffer length
at new ArrayBuffer (native)
at new Uint8Array (native)
at createBuffer (buffer.js:25:17)
at allocate (buffer.js:96:12)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:56:12)
at increaseBufferIfNecessary (/home/zenmonk/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/stream-buffers/lib/writable_streambuffer.js:58:23)
at [object Object].write (/home/zenmonk/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x8664+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/stream-buffers/lib/writable_streambuffer.js:65:5)
at doWrite (streamwritable.js:300:12)
at writeOrBuffer (streamwritable.js:286:5)
at [object Object].Writable.write (streamwritable.js:214:11)
at Request.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
at IncomingMessage. (/home/zenmonk/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/request/request.js:1255:12)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (streamreadable.js:153:18)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (streamreadable.js:111:10)
at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (httpcommon.js:124:22)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (httpclient.js:320:20)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (streamreadable.js:153:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (streamreadable.js:111:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was wrong with me too and I solved the problem by increasing the computer's memory

> this issue is identical to your
>
> [RangeError: Invalid array buffer length - Meteor JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908222/rangeerror-invalid-array-buffer-length-meteor-js/38927693#38927693)