# How to clear the error while installing @ngrx/store?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ngrx

This is the error I'm getting while installing `@ngrx/store`. Can anyone help to resolve this error

```
PS C:\Users\Welcome\ngrx-test> npm install @ngrx/store
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree     
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ngrx-test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~11.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^10.0.0" from @ngrx/store@10.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!   @ngrx/store@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-12T15_07_10_434Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try to remove node_module and cache clear after the try to reinstall ngrx-store. some time it is occur because of cache.

Comment: Had tried with the command -> npm cache clean --force, But its not working                        Is the given command is correct @Abhishek

Comment: Have you tried to delete node_module after that run this command `npm cache clear --force`?

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175200/how-to-delete-node-modules-deep-nested-folder-in-windows/32365809

Comment: Tried after deleting node modules..But its showing the same errror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the possible solutions you can try:

#### Deleting Node Modules and Cache

npm v5 and above:

```bash
npx rimraf ./**/node_modules

npm cache clear --force

npm install @ngrx/store
```

npm v4 or below:

```bash
npm install rimraf -g

rimraf .\**\node_modules

npm cache clear --force

npm install @ngrx/store
```

### Legacy Peer Dependencies

Try to install with the legacy peer dependencies option which will ignore `peerDependencies` while installing.

```bash
npm install @ngrx/store --legacy-peer-deps
```

#### Force

If that doesn't work, then try the force option.

```bash
npm install @ngrx/store --force
```

#### Different Version of `@ngrx/store`

If none of the options above work, you can try installing a different version of `@ngrx/store`.

```bash
npm install @ngrx/store@10.0.0
```

#### Different version of `node` & `npm`

Finally, as a last resort, you can try downgrading or upgrading your `node` and `npm` versions.

Here are [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version) on how to do so.